# How to get all the types of a collection through a Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some trouble writing some code (I might be tired), so I need some help here!

I have a model Wedding which has multiple Services through a join table. It is a Many-to-Many relationship.
And each of these Services have a specific service_type.

So basically I can do something like that:

```
myWeddingObject.services.first.service_type
```

My problem is that I would like to be able to get directly all the services types available for a wedding. For example:

```
myWeddingObject.service_types
```

And my question is, Am I obliged to write a method in my Wedding model where I would fetch all the services and check their types and then collect it or is there an other way that I did not see at first?

I thought of writing something like that in the Wedding model:

```
has_many :service_types, :through => :services
```

But as you can presume, it doesn't work. 
I might also have to add another model/SQL table?

I hope I have been clear enough and thanks for your help, I appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to just do

```
wedding.services.map(&:service_type).uniq
```

...Which will return an array of the service types. If you want has_many :through to work then you need to make service_type its own model. If you have a ton of service types that you want to be adding and editing, then a model is clearly the way to go. If it's just a small fixed set, then a separate model is probably overkill.